# Is it possible to convert QGIS QLM to SLD (w/ New Symbology)?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld, cartocss, qml

I have a QGIS project where I have created some nice styles using New Symbology. I would like to convert this to either SLD for use in GeoServer or CartoCSS for use in TileMill. I have tried saving the style as SLD directly from QGIS and a number of plugins, but I always get "`New Symbology not supported`" or "`<!--FeatureRendererV2 VectorFieldRenderer not implemented yet-->`".

I have also tried a number of plugins to convert the project/layer to tilemill or a mapserver project, but no dice.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the VectorFieldRenderer has not been implemented for SLD yet.

If you are using this:

[image]

it can't be exported to SLD.